# Apache Beam: Can step B depend on step A without passing outputs of A into B?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Is there a way to have PTransform B depend on PTransform A when A doesn’t produce any outputs? Or do I have to have A produce a dummy output that’s fed into B as a side input? An example use case is where I want to have the following pipeline:

```
Z = read file
A = count lines in file, and throw error if there are no lines
B = do something with the file
```

I want B to start only after A finishes, but A doesn’t produce any output PCollection useful to B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, but may not really be desirable in your case. Adding a dependency like this will slow down the parallel execution of the program, since B will need to wait for A to complete before it can start.

If you really want to do this, the way you described -- outputting an element and using that as the side input to B should work. Consider instead the following, which allows you to use the primitive `Count` transform to implement A, and moves all the logic into one place:

```
Z = read file
A = count lines in file
B = side input from A, throw error if the count of lines was zero,     
    otherwise do something with the file
```

Comment: Thanks. From what I understand, your suggestion is to make B a composite transform w/ 2 sub-steps, one that errors if the count is zero, and one that processes the file. But in this case, there is still no way to make the latter dependent on the former without having the erroring sub-step output an element that is used by the processing sub-step, right? (I.e., the order in which sub-steps are specified in a composite transform's `apply` function does not matter)

My motivation for wanting B to depend on A is that B gives an abstruse error if line count = 0, so I want A's to take precedence.